# Show the ring given by adjoining n-th roots to integers is not Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

I'm working on this problem for an algebra qualifying exam, and I haven't been able to make much progress.

For each positive integer $n$, let $R_n = \mathbb{Z}[2^{1/2}, \ldots, n^{1/n}]$ be a subring of the field of the real numbers. Prove that $R = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} R_n$ is not Noetherian.

My idea is to consider the ascending chain of ideals $(2^{1/2}) \subset (2^{1/2}, 3^{1/3}) \subset \cdots \subset R$ and show that the chain never stabilizes. Intuitively, I should show that adding an additional n-th root introduces new elements into the ideal each time so that the inclusion is always proper. However, I don't really know where to start with showing this.

Comment: Your idea is incorrect. The second ideal above in your choice is the whole ring, so the chain stabilizes.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  The ideal contains $1$ and then it contains everything.

Comment: Oh, I see, never mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $R$ is noetherian.

For each nonnegative integer $k$, if $x_k,n_k,y_k,e_k$ are given by
$$
\left\{
\begin{align*}
x_k&=2^{\bigl(2^{-k}\bigr)}\\[4pt]
n_k&=2^{\bigl(2^k\bigr)}\\[4pt]
y_k&=(n_k)^{\frac{1}{n_k}}\\[4pt]
e_k&=2^{2^k-2k}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
then identically we have
$$
x_k=(y_k)^{e_k}
$$
hence since $y_k\in R$, we get $x_k\in R$.

Then, noting that for all $k$ we have $x_k=(x_{k+1})^2$, it follows that
$$
(x_0)\subseteq(x_1)\subseteq(x_2)\subseteq(x_3)\subseteq\cdots
$$
is an ascending chain of principal ideals, hence, since R is noetherian, we must have
$$
(x_m)=(x_{m+1})
$$
for some $m$.

Then since $x_m=(x_{m+1})^2$, it follows that $x_{m+1}$ is a unit of $R$.

But then, noting that
$$
\bigl(x_{m+1}\bigr)^{2^{m+1}}=x_0=2
$$
it follows that $2$ is a unit of $R$, contradiction, since ${\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$ is not an algebraic integer, whereas all elements of $R$ are algebraic integers.